# DataGridView CellValueChanged triggers RowsRemoved

Tags: c#, datagridview

Ive got a C sharp application which recalculates a cost when a value in a cell has been changed. So far, my `DataGridView` has a `CellValueChanged()` event which is triggered when the cell value has been changed. However it also triggers the `RowsRemoved()` event of the DataGrid.
I've logged these events using the `RowIndex` and `RowCount` of the object of type `DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs` from the `RowsRemoved()` event, even though the cell value has been changed it states that the rows affected in the RowsRemoved() is all of them.

```
        Debug.WriteLine("Row removed: " + e.RowIndex);
        Debug.WriteLine("Row removed count: " + e.RowCount);
```

Code under the `CellValueChanged()` event:

```
if (dgridDetails.Rows.Count > 0){ 
            SetNewQuantity(e.RowIndex, Int32.Parse(dgridDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString()));
            RefreshDataGridView();
            Debug.WriteLine("Cell changed row: " + e.RowIndex);
            Debug.WriteLine("Cell changed column: " + e.ColumnIndex);
            Debug.WriteLine("New quantity: " + dgridDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value);

        }
```

The `RefreshDataGridView()` method:

```
decimal newTotalCost = 0;
        dgridDetails.Rows.Clear();
        dgridDetails.Refresh();
        foreach (var myLineItem in allItems)
        {
            //re add items on datagrid
            dgridDetails.Rows.Add(myLineItem.GetItemNumber(), myLineItem.GetItemName(),
                myLineItem.GetItemPrice(), myLineItem.GetQuantity(), myLineItem.GetCost());

            //keep new total figure
            newTotalCost += myLineItem.GetCost();
        }
        //show new total cost
        lblTotalCost.Text = newTotalCost.ToString();
```

How can I go about not triggering the RowsRemoved() when a Cell Value has been changed?

Comment: What is calling the RowsRemoved() event/can you post the code in RowsRemoved()?  It shouldn't be triggered just because you have a CellValueChanged() event.

Comment: please check my edit: @Yahtzee

Comment: What's going on in that `RefreshDataGridView()` method?

Comment: Added the code, im clearing the data grid view: @LarsTech

Comment: Don't you think `dgridDetails.Rows.Clear();` would trigger your RowsRemoved event?

Comment: snap, I totally missed that. thanks